# How do i know host server machine type with azure websites?

Tags: azure

When i deploy umbraco cms site on websites i think it will run on windows machine as it is asp.net. But if i deploy wordpress or joomla is it running on Linux?

How do I know if my host server is windows or linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure websites are hosted on Windows OS. Windows Azure websites are running in a huge server farm which in Windows Server OS based and your content goes to a single location name “content share”. All the instance to your websites take the content from a single share and run it in Windows Server OS farm.

It does not matter if you are using Wordpress, Joomla or Umbraco. If you selected to create a Windows Azure WebSites then it will be hosted on Windows OS with IIS and W3WP potentially will be the host process to host your website. Windows Azure Websites are designed in a way that you don’t need tio give attention to which OS is running instead give full focus to your application development and keep it running.

You host server will be **Linux** only when you have selected to create a Windows Azure Virtual Machine and deployed Linux OS based VHD to it.